# How to take input from featured mobile phone in cocos creator?

Tags: input, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d, cocos2d-x-js

I am beginner to cocos creator and I came to know cocos has Keyboard,DeviceMotion and Mouse input event but I want to know how to take input from featured mobile phone having number pad?

Will it be similar as taking input from keyboard as number or there is something else.

Comment: It seems reasonable that it should come in as keyboard input. The best way to verify would be to test with such a device. What do your tests show so far?

Comment: @DMGregory I tried with key board input and it's working, I have only tested for numbered keys not sure about other.

Comment: Let us know once you've tested a case that's not working as desired, and we can help you solve that problem.

Comment: Sure @DMGregory